# Pentaho Kettle FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, pentaho, sqoop

I am trying to import a `MySQL` database into my `HDFS` using the `Sqoop import` component, with `Pentaho Kettle`, but I getting this error in the log file:

```
ERROR [ImportTool] Encountered IOException running import job: 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: 
Output directory hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root already exists
```

However, My hadoop filesystem is clean, so this error is impossible!
I can´t understand what can be happening.

Comment: Provide please your configuration for sqoop import job. You can switch to command line tab and copy for us its value.

Comment: You mention "hadoop filesystem is clean", to make sure again, can you please paste output of hdfs dfs -ls /user ?